# Passing a Dataframe column in where clause of a SQL (Column is of type string)

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to pass a Pandas Dataframe column in the where clause of a SQL. This column is of type string.

```
bill_id, product_name
101, prod_a
102, prod_b
103, prod_c
104, prod_d


prod_list = ','.join(["'" + str(x) + "'" for x in df['product_name'].tolist()])
```

I am trying to pass product name in the where clause of a SQL as below:

```
query = """select prod_id, product_name from products where product_name in (%s)""" % prod_list
```

This however seems to return back an empty Dataframe when I know there are matches available for values in that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way to handle this is to manually build the `WHERE IN (...)` clause using the correct number of placeholders corresponding to the input list.  Then, bind that list to the statement as you typically would do.

```py
products = df['product_name'].tolist()
where = "(%s" + ", %s"*(len(products) - 1) + ")"
query = """
SELECT prod_id, product_name
FROM products
WHERE product_name IN """
query = query + where

cursor.execute(query, products)
```

Note that for a product input list of 3 elements, the above code snippet would generate the following raw SQL query:

```sql
SELECT prod_id, product_name
FROM products
WHERE product_name IN (%s, %s, %s)
```